# Iterate over i,j in a function returning two arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to accept two arrays from a function and iterate over value pairs in an array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(10).astype(np.uint8)
a[0:4] = 1
hist = np.zeros(4)

values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
for u, c in zip(values, counts):
    hist[u] += c
# This works. hist: [6. 4. 0. 0.]

# for u, c in zip(np.unique(a, return_counts=True)):  # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
#     hist[u] += c
# for u, c in np.unique(a, return_counts=True):  # IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
#     hist[u] += c
```

Code works if I first accept two arrays, then use `for k,v in zip(arr1, arr2)`
Is it possible two write `for k,v in function_returning_two_arrays(args)` as a one line statement?

---

Update. Both `zip(*arg)` and `[arg]` work. Can you please elaborate on this syntax, please. A link to an article would be enough. Then I can accept the answer. I got it that a `*` unpacks a tuple, but what does `[some_tupple]` do?

Comment: `for u, c in [np.unique(a, return_counts=True)]`?

Comment: Yes there is the `*` operator for that. Do something like `for u, c in zip(*np.unique(a, return_counts=True)):`. The `*` means: please unpack the returned tuple and give the elements as arguments to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `unique` step, this just basic python.

```
In [78]: a = np.zeros(10).astype(np.uint8)
    ...: a[0:4] = 1
    ...: ret = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
```

`unique` returns a tuple of arrays, which can be used as is, or unpacked into 2 variables.  I think unpacking makes the code clearer.

```
In [79]: ret
Out[79]: (array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([6, 4]))
In [80]: values, counts = ret
In [81]: values
Out[81]: array([0, 1], dtype=uint8)
In [82]: counts
Out[82]: array([6, 4])
```

The following just makes a list with 1 item - the tuple

```
In [83]: [ret]
Out[83]: [(array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([6, 4]))]
```

That's different from making a list of the two arrays - which just changes the tuple "wrapper" to a list:

```
In [84]: [values, counts]
Out[84]: [array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([6, 4])]
```

`zip` takes multiple items (it has a `*args` signature)

```
In [85]: list(zip(*ret))                 # same as zip(values, counts)
Out[85]: [(0, 6), (1, 4)]
In [86]: [(i,j) for i,j in zip(*ret)]    # using that in an iteration
Out[86]: [(0, 6), (1, 4)]
In [87]: [(i,j) for i,j in zip(values, counts)]
Out[87]: [(0, 6), (1, 4)]
```

So it pairs the nth element of `values` with the nth element of `counts`

Iteration on the `[ret]` list does something entirely different, or rather it does nothing - compare with `Out[83]:

```
In [88]: [(i,j) for i,j in [ret]]
Out[88]: [(array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([6, 4]))]
```

I think of `list(zip(*arg))` as a list version of `transpose`:

```
In [90]: np.transpose(ret)
Out[90]: 
array([[0, 6],
       [1, 4]])
In [91]: [(i,j) for i,j in np.transpose(ret)]
Out[91]: [(0, 6), (1, 4)]
```